# parameterized trigger - include child's console output in parent's console output

Tags: jenkins

I'm starting a job via the parameterized trigger plugin.  If I want to avoid clicking through to the tiggered job's console to see the output, is there a way I could just have this included in the parent job's console output (i.e. right where it says "Waiting for the completion of...")

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

not exactly .... but what you can do is to edit the view in which your jobs are displayed and add another coloumn to display the console out put window of a downstream jobs.

Alternativley I can recommand the "Build flow plugin" which helps you manage the flow of the build.
here is the link

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin

explore the plugins...there usualy is something that matches your needs.

Comment: Can you mark this as the answer please if it has helped you?